# How to determine the actual usage of the memory in the page file?

Tags: c#, .net

How to determine the actual usage of the memory in the page file?
there is PagedSystemMemorySize property in the Process class. Maybe I can sum these properties of the all processes?

Comment: It's an answer that's wrong/out of date as soon as you know it. What's the reason for wanting it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my friend asked me to help her with her lab